# Get running time from table with start / stop event datetime only

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need your help to get the total running duration per day from a table when I record only start and stop events:

| id | ts | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-26 09:00:00.589016 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020-12-26 10:25:00.589016 | 1 |
| 3 | 2020-12-26 19:30:45.644092 | 0 |
| 4 | 2020-12-26 22:30:00.554092 | 1 |

0 = stop event

1 = start event

The difficulty here is to compute the duration between start and stop events but also:
if a start event is the day before, include the duration between midnight and the first start event (in this example 9h)

Any idea to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

For each row with `event = 0` and non existing previous row of the same day with `event = 1` create another row with `ts` at midnight of the same day.
Similarly for each row with `event = 1` and non existing next row of the same day with `event = 0` create another row with `ts` at `23:59:59.99999` of the same day.

This can be done in a CTE.

Then use window function `LAG()` for each row with `event = 0` to get the starting time and with `strftime()` calculate the difference and finally aggregate on all the differences of each day:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ts, event FROM tablename
  UNION ALL
  SELECT datetime(date(t.ts)), 1 
  FROM tablename t
  WHERE event = 0 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename WHERE event = 1 AND date(ts) = date(t.ts) AND ts < t.ts)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date(t.ts) || ' 23:59:59.999999', 0 
  FROM tablename t
  WHERE event = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename WHERE event = 0 AND date(ts) = date(t.ts) AND ts > t.ts)
)
SELECT date(ts) date,
       SUM(strftime('%s', ts) - strftime('%s', prev_ts)) total
FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(ts) OVER (ORDER BY ts) prev_ts
  FROM cte
)
WHERE event = 0
GROUP BY date
```

You will get the total per day in seconds.
If you want better accuracy you can use the function `julianday()` instead of `strftime()`:

```
..............................
SELECT date(ts) date,
       SUM(julianday(ts) - julianday(prev_ts)) * 24 * 3600 total
..............................
```

Or, a more efficient way:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
    LAG(ts, 1, date(ts)) OVER (PARTITION BY date(ts) ORDER BY ts) start_ts,
    event = 1 AND LEAD(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY date(ts) ORDER BY ts) IS NULL flag
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT date(ts) date, 
       SUM(
         CASE flag
           WHEN 0 THEN strftime('%s', ts) - strftime('%s', start_ts)
           WHEN 1 THEN strftime('%s', date(ts) || ' 23:59:59.999999') - strftime('%s', ts)
         END  
       ) total
FROM cte
WHERE event = 0 OR flag = 1
GROUP BY date
```

Note that this code works only if all datetimes are in the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.ssssss` (I noticed that in your sample data there is a value that is not of that format: `'2020-12-26 9:00:00.589016'`).

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3290d50cb0a73e222670c9fe5d8fb770).
Results:

```
> date       | total
> :--------- | ----:
> 2020-12-26 | 70544
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Times are already in a datetime_64 format as shown below:
ts  event
id
1   2020-12-25 23:55:09.589016  1
2   2020-12-26 00:05:18.589016  0
3   2020-12-26 09:00:00.589016  1
4   2020-12-26 10:25:00.589016  0
5   2020-12-26 19:30:45.644092  1
6   2020-12-26 22:30:00.554092  0

You can do the following:

```
dfs = df.loc[df.event == 1]
dfs = dfs.rename(columns={"ts": "Start"})
dfs.reset_index(drop= True, inplace=True)
dfnd = df.loc[df.event==0]
dfnd = dfnd.rename(columns={"ts": "Stop"})
dfnd.reset_index(drop= True, inplace=True)
dfdur = dfnd.Stop - dfs.Start
```

Which Yields the following:

```
0          0 days 00:10:09
1          0 days 01:25:00
2   0 days 02:59:14.910000
```

Comment: Thanks for this direction, sounds promising but not working as is. Let's imagine this sequence: (0 2020-12-26 00:00:00.000000   0), (1 2020-12-26 11:00:00.000000    1), (2 2020-12-26 13:00:00.000000   0), (3 2020-12-26 23:59:59.999999   0), the calculated duration is not the one expected

Answer (score 0):

You can find the difference between the start and stop times for each interval, and then sum the latter result, grouped by the day:

```
with _events as (select row_number() over (order by t1.id) r, substr(t1.ts, 0, instr(t1.ts, " ")) day, t1.* from test t1),
    events as (select (select sum(e2.event = 1 and e2.r < e1.r) from _events e2) c, e1.* from _events e1)
select day_r.day, sum(diff) from (
    select e3.day, (julianday(max(e3.ts)) - julianday(min(e3.ts)))*24*60*60 diff 
    from events e3 
    group by e3.c
   ) 
day_r group by day_r.day;
```